# Trying to load excel file into ms-access where a text field contains the @ symbol

Tags: excel, ms-access

First Post here...

My access app will have a monthly process where the user must load excel files containing account balances.  One field occasionally contains the @ symbol as part of the Account Number - this field is a short text field in the database table.

Access flags this a violation.  Is there anyway for access to support this character?  if not is there any way to automatically remove the character or replace it with another character?

The following is what I am using to load the excel file into access...

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 9, "TempAccountBalances", [TempVars]![varTBFileName], True

The actual excel file contains 4182@ in the Account number field in several cases.

The file imports properly for all excel rows except those that contain the @ character in the Account# field.  Each of those rows generate a row in a newly created table called xxx_ImportErrors with a TypeConversionFailure in the Error Field.  Access auto created that table on it own

Update...  A little more information...
When I import the file using the Access Ribbon - External Data - New Data Source - Excel File
It imports the Account# fields without error when importing into a new table

But when I import into an existing table i get the same failed rows as the DoCmd above.  ALL the Account# field properties in the new table are identical to the existing TempAccountTable used above ???

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: That is a very odd account number. Why does this happen? What import method are you using? Edit question to show code. I just tested this and had no issue importing data.

Answer (score 0):

OK - so this was caused by Access determining the field type based on the first X rows of the imported excel file. So I need to use an Import Specification file to force the field type to what I need.  That caused me another issue which I'll post separately.